# Does a Möbius transformation having fixed points not on the object return the entire complex plane as image?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

This arises from a (very early) exercise in H. A. Priestley's Introduction to complex analysis. Given the transformation $\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ we were to find the invariant (=fixed?) points, which are $\pm$ i, and apply the transformation to various objects.
When applied to the real axis, the transformation appeared to return the whole of the complex plane—every $z$  was included.
I used the inverse point form for the real axis, ie $|z-i|=|z+i|$. substituted for $z$, and after multiplying through by $z+1$ and dividing through by $1-i$, (not sure whether this is legitimate...) obtained$$|z-1|=|iz-i|$$ which is true, I think, for all $z$.

Later:
I tried the same transformation on $|z|=2$ which doesn't go through $i$ or -$i$ either but it returned a perfectly normal looking circle...which didn't involve the 'fixed points' either.

Comment: if $z$ is real, so is $\frac{z-1}{z+1}$

Comment: @ Will Jagy. But one can get an image that involves points that were not on the object—as in the case of this transformation applied to the unit circle. And the imaginary axis, I think, goes to the unit circle. I am puzzled when the equation for the image has to use points from the object and when it can range over the whole plane. If I haven't made mistakes, my example is a case where allowing z the full range doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Möbius transformation $z \rightarrow f(z)=\frac {z-1}{z+1}$ can be re-written as:-

$z \rightarrow f(z) = \frac{(z-1)(\bar{z} + 1)}{(z+1)(\bar{z} + 1)} = \frac{|z|^2 -1 + 2i \text{Im}(z)}{|z+1|^2}$

If $z$ is on the real axis then $\text{Im}(z)=0$ so $f(z)$ is also real i.e. $f$ maps the real axis to itself.

If $z$ is on the imaginary axis then $|z+1|=|z-1|$ so $|f(z)|=1$ i.e. $f$ maps the imaginary axis to the unit circle.

If $|z|=1$ then $f(z) = \frac{2\text{Im}(z)}{|z+1|^2}$ which is purely imaginary i.e. $f$ maps the unit circle back to the imaginary axis.

$\pm i$ are mapped to themselves and $\infty \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow -1 \rightarrow \infty$. In fact, you can show that $f^4(z)=z$ for all $z$.

In general, a Möbius transformation is a 1-1 mapping of the extended complex plane $C \cup {\infty}$ to itself. So the image  of a subset of the complex plane (such as the real axis) cannot be the whole complex plane, otherwise the mapping would not be 1-1.

Comment: That's so helpful! I was tying myself in knots over Priestley's next exercise which has a similar but more complicated transformation. A method similar to yours should work as well with this one.